# Kubernetes Deployment fails with error

Tags: kubernetes

- Kubernetes Version: 1.16
- OS: CentOS7 hosted on Google Cloud

Tried to run a deployment on master node with the following manifest file:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx
  labels:
    app: nginx
  namespace: deployment-demo
  annotations:
    monitoring: "true"
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: nginx
        name: nginx
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
        resources:
          limits:
            memory: "2Gi"
            cpu: "1000m"
          requests: 
            memory: "1Gi"
            cpu: "500m"
```

And it trowed the following error:

```
**[root@kubemaster deployment-demo]# kubectl create -f nginx-deploy.yaml --validate=false
The Deployment "" is invalid:
* metadata.name: Required value: name or generateName is required
* spec.selector: Required value
* spec.template.metadata.labels: Invalid value: map[string]string(nil): `selector` 
   does not match template `labels`
* spec.template.spec.containers: Required value**
```

Please advise regarding what I am missing here.

Comment: I tried to `kubectl apply` your config and everything worked as expected. Can you check your `kubectl version` to see if the client/master version is in compliance with the [version skew policy](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/release/version-skew-policy/#kubectl)?  You can also try your `kubectl apply` again with the `-v=10` flag to get some debug information.